# Array key value to string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I want to convert an array of this style:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [post_id] => 20752 ) [1] => Array ( [post_id] => 20753 ) )
```

into the string:

```
20752, 20753
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: First use `array_column()` and then `implode()`.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function with combination of [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode(', ', array_column($data, 'post_id'));
```