# PHP convert 2 dimensional array to string

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am trying to convert following array:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '611' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '610' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '608' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '607' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '606' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string '605' (length=3)
```

**Expected output:** `611, 610, 608, 607, 606, 605`

I tried to do this:

```
 foreach ($array as $sub) {
     $str = implode(',', $sub);
 }
```

but I got `605`

Could you explain what I am doing wrong

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401669/array-key-value-to-string-in-php/46401757#46401757

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is one error in foreach. You always replace previous value, you just need to do:

```
 foreach ($array as $sub) {
     $str .= implode(',', $sub);
 }
```